# How to check the cluster status of Redshift using boto3 module in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-redshift, boto3

I need to check if the Redshift cluster is paused or available using Python. I am aware of the module **boto3** which further provides a method **describe_clusters()**. I am not sure how to proceed further to write a Python script for that.

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
    import boto3
    import pandas as pd

    DWH_CLUSTER_IDENTIFIER = 'Your clusterId'
    KEY='Your AWS Key'
    SECRET='Your AWS Secret'
    
    # Get client to connect redshift
    redshift = boto3.client('redshift',
                           region_name="us-east-1",
                           aws_access_key_id=KEY,
                           aws_secret_access_key=SECRET
                           )
   
    # Get cluster list as it is in AWS console
    myClusters = redshift.describe_clusters()['Clusters']
    
    if len(myClusters) > 0:
        df = pd.DataFrame(myClusters)
        myCluster=df[df.ClusterIdentifier==DWH_CLUSTER_IDENTIFIER.lower()]
        
        print("My cluster status is: {}".format(myCluster['ClusterAvailabilityStatus'].item()))
    else:
        print('No clusters available')
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it